# Cannot drag and drop columns in ag-grid toolbar

Tags: drag-and-drop, ag-grid

I am looking at [the first demo on the row grouping page of the ag-grid documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/) and the drag and drop behavior does not seem to be correct.

I am able to remove columns from the *Row Groups* section, but I cannot add them back again. I have tried this both on firefox and chrome. I am on a mac.

I also see the following warnings in my console:

```
ag-Grid: count not find callback onExpandClicked
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.min.js:
ag-grid-enterprise.min.js:2 ag-Grid: count not find callback onSelectClicked
(anonymous) @ ag-grid-enterprise.min.js:2
ag-grid-enterprise.min.js:2 ag-Grid: count not find callback onFilterTextChanged
```

So, it looks like some callbacks are not being registered, and this is preventing drag and drop to work.

I also created a [plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xtPbAztpG14bleAF9bgy?p=preview), which may make things easier to verify. Please not that this plunkr is unchanged from the demo linked to above.

I have tried with ag-grid versions 15.0.0 and 17.0.0 on both firefox and chrome.

So, why is drag and drop not working?

Comment: Are you trying to use the ToolPanel dragging?  If so, you'll need "enableRowGroup: true" on the column def, not "rowGroup:true"

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. It looks like the demos were out of date. `rowGroup:true` no longer works. If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. I've already raised a github issue for this.

Comment: Done!  I think rowGroup might actually still do something outside of the tool panel, but I haven't looked into it further.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the plunkr, it seems like there might be a typo and/or an outdated config demo. You "**enableRowGroup**:true" not "rowGroup:true".